# Sherlock Actionbar custom design

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, styling

I will be very thankfull if anyone will help me find out some details about customizing sherlock actionbar.

To be more concrete: I need an action bar with four buttons. Two small buttons on the sides of the bar (on on the left side and second on the right), and one "paired" radiobutton in the middle of the bar.
When I say "paired" I mean something like in iOS when there are two buttons positioned near each other and when I press one - the second is unpressed and vice versa.
All in all it should look like this.

[image: teoretical actionbar sherlock]

Is it even possible to make this or I should forget about using the wonderful sherlock creature?

Answer (score 6):

I would personally abandon the idea of using ActionBarSherlock and instead just implement this using your own layout resource.

As a user of ActionBarSherlock I can say it's a fantastic library, as it essentially allows you to use the ActionBar API across all devices, including pre-Honeycomb, meaning you don't have to code a separate UI to suit pre-Honeycomb device. But the point of ActionBarSherlock is that it just provides APIs that are equivalent to those of the native ActionBar. And the problem is that the ActionBar is restrictive in what you can creatively do with it, because it is designed to offer specific functionality and controls that kind of fit around how Google want you to implement your UI. In a nutshell, you can specify a custom layout `View` that appears somewhere within the bar. You can also control which menu items appear as action items placed on the right-hand side of the bar (though it is ultimately still up to the system, based on screen space, if such items are made visible on the bar). The bar also allows you to implement some very special functionality (Action Views, Action Providers, etc.)

But if you're looking to create a very customised layout like the one you've pictured, *and* you don't need the special functionality that the ActionBar (or ActionBarSherlock) provides, then you might be better off doing it from scratch.

Comment: The situation is that I need to have a somekindof header in my application, which will stay in its place when user navigates from one activity to another. For this I have changed from activities to fragments. But again the second trouble is that one of the fragments should contain a map. Thats why I need sherlock. Maybe there is a way to hide a bar? And wouldnt my "custom" bar stay in place or it will slide with content on fragments transition?

Comment: By the way, a gentle reminder - you need to accept more answers.

Comment: You can easily hide the native/sherlock bar using theme settings for your activity: 

<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">

Also, a custom bar can be kept in place by using a global layout file with the bar and a fragment holder. If you do transactions on the fragment holder, the bar will stick around.

However, based on the situation you describe in your comment, I would recommend just sticking with ActionBarSherlock - unless you have a very specific reason not to. There is a reason Google tries to force a strict structure for navigation: it's familiar to users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make your Sherlock ActionBar like you show above. you have to set custom View to your SherLock ActionBAr. Just few lines of code

```
   getSupportActionBar()
            .setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(
            R.layout.your_custom_layout);
```

and you custom layout should be RelativeLayout something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```