# Spinner in actionbar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to show a spinner beside the action bar title, could I know how to do that. For normal title, "setTitle("")" is being used, but if I want to customize the header instead of just a text view, how is it possible. Here is the mainactivity and baseactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

    private Fragment mContent;

    public MainActivity(){
        super(R.string.app_name);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        if (mContent == null)
            mContent = new MainView();

        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent).commit();

        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new RandomList()).commit();

        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    }

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment){
        mContent = fragment;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        getSlidingMenu().showContent();
    }   

}
public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private int mTitleRes;
    protected ListFragment mFrag;

    public BaseActivity(int titleRes){
        mTitleRes = titleRes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(mTitleRes);


        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFrag = new RandomList();
        ft.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        ft.commit();

        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidth(15);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffset(60);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;
        }
        return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class BasePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        private ViewPager mPager;

        public BasePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager vp){
            super(fm);
            mPager = vp;
            mPager.setAdapter(this);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                addTab(new RandomList());
            }
        }

        public void addTab(Fragment frag){
            mFragments.add(frag);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return mFragments.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer
here is what is needed

```
 getSupportActionBar()
            .setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(
            R.layout.your_custom_layout);
```

[Sherlock Actionbar custom design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877544/sherlock-actionbar-custom-design?rq=1)

the above link has got detailed answer